# SwiftUI fit VStack children into the frame

Tags: swiftui

I'm adding a `SwiftUI` view into the `UIKit` view controller. This `SwiftUI` view has `VStack` wrapping a bunch of buttons and labels. in small screens the form is cut off from the bottom. Is it possible to dynamically change the spacing for the parent `VStack` to make it fit all the children into the frame?

[image]

This is the SwiftUI view:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        logo
              
        Text("Connection")
        
        ZStack {} // Login
        
        ZStack {} // Sign up with email
        
        HStack {} // Horizontal divider
        
        ZStack {} // Apple login
        
        ZStack {} // Google login
        
        ZStack {} // Facebook login
    }
    
}
```

This is how the SwiftUI added to the ViewController:

```
// VeiwController.Swift

override func loadView() {
    view = UIView()
    view.addSubview(navigationBar)
    
    let connectionViewSwiftUI = ConnectionSubviewSwiftUI()
    let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: connectionViewSwiftUI)
    addChild(hostingController)
    view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
    hostingController.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    navigationBar.delegate = self
    navigationBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        navigationBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        navigationBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        navigationBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        navigationBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: kNavbarHeight)
    ])
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        hostingController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.bottomAnchor),
        hostingController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        hostingController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
    ])
    
    hostingController.didMove(toParent: self)
}
```

Comment: not sure, but try `VStack(spacing: 0)` and then add a `Spacer()` between every element.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone SE (2nd Gen)

[image: iPhone SE (2nd Gen)]

iPhone 11

[image: iPhone 11]

You can pre-calculate the overall height your view can take and then add a condition if screen height is less then your view's overall height then do some workaround to fix all the content on the screen, you can use this approach to achieve what you're looking for

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    
    // MARK: - BODY
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20){
            Group{
                CustomBtn(text: "Button1", height: 40)
                CustomBtn(text: "Button2", height: 40)
                CustomBtn(text: "Button3", height: 40)
                CustomBtn(text: "Button4", height: 40)
                CustomBtn(text: "Button5", height: 40)
                CustomBtn(text: "Button6", height: 40)
                CustomBtn(text: "Button7", height: 40)
                CustomBtn(text: "Button8", height: 40)
                
                if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height < 700{
                    HStack(spacing: 8){
                        CustomBtn(text: "Button9", height: 40)
                        CustomBtn(text: "Button10", height: 40)
                        CustomBtn(text: "Button11", height: 40)
                        CustomBtn(text: "Button12", height: 40)
                    }
                }else{
                    CustomBtn(text: "Button9", height: 40)
                    CustomBtn(text: "Button10", height: 40)
                    CustomBtn(text: "Button11", height: 40)
                    CustomBtn(text: "Button12", height: 40)
                }
            }//: GROUP
        }//: VSTACK
        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
    }
}

// MARK: - PREVIEW

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}
```

CustomButton

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomBtn: View {
    
    var text: String
    var height: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {}) {
            Spacer()
            Text(text)
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(height: height)
        .background(.orange)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
}

struct CustomBtn_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CustomBtn(text: "Button", height: 40)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not what I wanted, I wanted to know if is there any way to make the view change the spacing automatically to contain all contents.